# Cutomizing multi-level slug in wordpress for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have a custom post type and would like where the URL structure is as follows:

```
www.example.com/books/book-1
www.example.com/books/book-2
www.example.com/books/book-3
```

Is it possible to customize the URL front on a post-by-post basis? For instance:

```
www.example.com/fiction-books/book-1
www.example.com/diy-books/book-2
www.example.com/cookbooks/book-3
```

I can think of some inconvenient workaround using parent pages, but am hoping there is something in my `register_post_type` args that will allow for this.

This is how I'm registering the custom post type:

```
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Books", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Book", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Books", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "books", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_position" => 5,
        "supports" => array( "title" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "books", $args );
```